# Overestimating in limit convergence proofs

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I understand that for all $\epsilon >0$ there exists an $N \in \mathbb{R}_+$ such that $n>N$ implies $|a_n−L|<\epsilon$, for all $n>N$.

But I find myself overestimating. For example, working on this HW proof that $\frac{3n^2+2n+1}{n^2 +n+2}$ converges to $3$ I've estimated that this only works when ϵ is falls within a specific range instead of any $\epsilon>0$.

However from my understanding, $\epsilon$ has to be ANY Real number greater than $0$, not just a real number greater than $0$.

I think I take a wrong turn after this point in my HW:

$$\left| \frac{3n^2+2n+1}{n^2 +n+2}-3\right| < \left| \frac{-n-5}{n^2 +n+2}\right|$$

My next steps after taking it out of the absolute value were to make the numerator 6n and make the denominator the easily factorable and smaller $n^2 +n+1/4$, but it doesn't seem to work for all $\epsilon$.

I think my understanding would improve if I understood a similar line of reasoning:

Similarly, in this example,

Prove $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \frac{4n^3+3n}{n^3 −6} = 4.$

I understand why after simplifying the numerator $3n + 24$ is estimated as $27n$, but I can't fully follow why the denominator is **specifically** chosen as $(n^3)/2$? Why not $n^3$ alone? The second example, btw is from

Elementary Analysis
The Theory of Calculus Second Edition
By Kenneth A. Ross
Springer

Any hints and critiques on estimating better would be appreciated. Thanks

---

Additional context for 2nd example:

![example 3, page 40, from Elementary Analysis
The Theory of Calculus Second Edition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBoTG.jpg)

[image: ending of proof for example 3]

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: I've edited the post to use MathJax so it's easier to read.  You can look click on "edited..." to see the changes as an example of how to use it.

Comment: Could you provide more details on your work in the first problem?  Your argument is not clear.

Comment: I then estimated $$ |(−n−5)/(n2+n+2)|$$ to $$(n+5)//(n2+n+2)|$$ and then to $$6n//(n2+n+2)| $$which is less than $$6n/(n2+n+1/4)$$ (so the denominator could be factored. This is less than 6 times $$$(n+.5)/((n+.5)^2) $$. My reasoning is that is that if I set N to be larger than the original |an-L|, then an epsilon larger than N will be larger than |an-L| And be a good basis for an n>N in the proof.

Comment: @Forever_A_Student Don't try to factor or be clever or anything, just bound it! You can use crude bounds!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea behind these proofs is you want to bound $|a_n-L|$ by something that can be made smaller than $\epsilon$. For example with $\frac{3n^2+2n+1}{n^2+n+2}$. We do the "prep work" (**NOT THE PROOF**).

$$\left| \frac{3n^2+2n+1}{n^2+n+2}-3\right|=\left|\frac{3n^2+2n+1-3n^2-3n-6}{n^2+n+2} \right|=\left|\frac{-n-5}{n^2+n+2} \right|$$

Which is what you have! Now you just need to bound this by something.

$$\left|\frac{-n-5}{n^2+n+2} \right|=\left|\frac{n+5}{n^2+n+2}\right|\leq\left|\frac{n+5n}{n^2}\right|=\frac{6}{n}$$
That bound is constructed by making the top bigger and the bottom smaller.

**Now here is the proof.**

Let $\epsilon>0$. By the Archimedian property of the natural numbers there is some $N\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $N>\frac{6}{\epsilon}$. If $n>N$, then:
$$n>\frac{6}{\epsilon}$$
$$\epsilon >\frac{6}{n}\geq \left|\frac{n+5}{n^2+n+2}\right|=\left| \frac{3n^2+2n+1}{n^2+n+2}-3\right|$$

Thus the claim is proven.

The way of dealing with these problems is knowing how to bound things and don't be afraid of some large bounds. With your second example, I don't know the full argument so I can't comment.

Comment: Thanks! I think that was it. I was concerned that by estimating the denominator to be $n^2$ I would be taking too much away. I've edited the original question to post the context of the second question. It seems that I need to take "larger" bounds, but I wonder about the reasoning in the second example. I assume that the $$n^3$$ is retained to keep the estimate close to the original denominator, but why divide by 2? Would it have been wrong to estimate it without the division by 2?